# Speed up wait time in order to change Minecraft Username?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I would really like to change my username in Minecraft, but I have to wait two days. I know it sounds stupid, but is there any way to speed up time in order to change it sooner?

The username I chose was really, really stupid, so I'm eager to change it.

Comment: I thought it was a 30 day waiting period between name changes?

Answer (score 4):

Had a read through the [official Minecraft Username FAQ](https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/articles/928638-minecraft-usernames) and here is what I've come up with:

- When you first set up your account, you are given an undisclosed wait to change your name. **If you are asked to wait for 2 days I would be content with this resolution, as..**
- When you change you username, you have a 30 day cooldown before you can change your name again (so be sure you pick a name you like).
- Once you change your name, you are given 37 days (the cooldown plus a week) to revert back to your old name, before the old name is made available to other players.
- Although I can not tell you how, **your old username will still be viewable by other players**. They say this is to assist in identifying players that change their name to avoid bad reputation, and I'm not sure how this applys with the 37-day cooling off period.

Lastly, the FAQ details that the moderators will not assist in changing your name, as they have designed the system to be self serve.

To answer your original question, yes. You can fast track a name change. **The moderators themselves have the power to instantly change your name.** That said, they have put a lot of effort into ensuring the system is self-serve. You are more likely to annoy the developers, and gain yourself some bad reputation, then succeed in having them over-ride the 2 day waiting period.

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to wait the waiting period, before being able to change your name again.

There's a chance that if you contacted support, that they would be able to change your name for you sooner, especially if your name is against their naming rules.

If you're asking if you can change the computer time in order to trick it into thinking that more time has passed, no you cannot do that as the time is based on the server time. So you would have to change the time on the computers that host the player databases. Unless you're a hacker or work there, it's unlikely that you'd be able to do that.

Comment: this doesnt answer their question at all. They are asking if they can speed up the two days

Comment: @Timelord64 you mean they're asking if they can time travel??

Comment: They are asking if they can speed up the cooling off period. Rather then sarcasm and condescending response, a quick look at the minecraft username faq, where there are similar questions about username cooldowns, might help your understanding.

Comment: @Timelord64 I wasn't being condescending, it was a genuine response, which I felt answered the question, albeit a bit bluntly. I have since edited into a more verbose answer.